# Codeigniter always load default controller on subdomain or subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I know that there are a lot of solutions for this problem. But i've tried a lot of difference aproaches and non of them help.
Explanation of the problem: When i set my CI project on the host webserver in a subfolder or Subdomain it only loads the default controller. On local everything works fine.

- I've tried setting the Uri Protocol from "AUTO" to "REQUEST_URI", didn't help
- I've tried many different htaccess solutions, but didn't help
- I've tried working on old-school index.php urls, didn't help
- I've tried disabling all routes, didn't help

  **EDIT things tried:**
- I've tried removing klanten from base url, like suggested. didn't help (suggested by @tomexsans)

My Settings:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";  
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url']= 'http://www.mywebsite.nl/klanten';
```

or for the subdomain:

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://klanten.mywebsite.nl/';
```

My htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|stylesheets|javascript)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm running on a php 5.3.15 with CI 2.1.2

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something, that i don't like to do, to fix it. 
First of all, yes i tried update CI but this didn't do anything..

So my solution for CI2.1.2 was the following:

Core/URI.php :185

```
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($uri, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === 0)
    {
        if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "::1")
        {
            $uri = substr($uri, strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
        }
        else
        {
            $uri = ltrim ($uri,'/');    
        }
```

This was a working solution for me when i place the CI website in a Subdomain, When you place it in a subfolder the else should probably be like this:

```
$uri = ltrim ($uri,'/subfolder/');
```

I hope it helps anyone, if there is a better way to achieve this, please say so.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load default controller? have you tried the settings on `routes` file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'klanten';
```

Comment: sorry @tomexsans, i think that you didn't understand my question well. My default controller is loading fine, in fact a bit too fine.. It always loads. I can't navigate to another page because whatever the url is, it always shows my default_controller..

Comment: @spons have you tried removing the `klanten` from your base_url?

Comment: Yeah i tried that, but then it doesn't load my css and images because it redirects to the root folder and not to klanten. Also when i navigate to another controller in that case it gives the default-controller. like before.